# Как пробежаться по массиву объектов, выделить определенное свойство, изменить его, и вернуть новое значение данного свойства в массив?

Tags: javascript, localstorage

имеется массив объектов
`var tasks = [{
        name: "Задача № 1",
        selectedProject: 'select project',
        dateBegin: new Date('07 24, 2016 19:58:49'),
        dateFinish: new Date('07 24, 2016 19:58:59')
      }, {
        name: "Задача № 2",
        selectedProject: 'timer',
        dateBegin: new Date('07 25, 2016 19:58:30'),
        dateFinish: new Date('07 25, 2016 19:59:15')
      }]`

я при определенном действии сохраняю его в local Storage

```
localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(newTasks));
```

при загрузке страницы я достаю этот массив с LS

```
var newTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"))
```

теперь мне надо пробежаться по этому массиву отпарсировать даты и записать их в массив,я делаю это так

```
for(var i=0; i < newTasks.length; i++)
```

new Date(Date.parse(newTasks[i].dateBegin));

```
for(var i=0; i < newTasks.length; i++)
```

new Date(Date.parse(newTasks[i].dateFinish));

как мне вернуть уже отпарсированные даты в массив???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это основы программирования - очевидно присваивание

```
for(var i=0; i < newTasks.length; i++){
  newTasks[i].dateBegin = new Date(Date.parse(newTasks[i].dateBegin));
  newTasks[i].dateFinish = new Date(Date.parse(newTasks[i].dateFinish));
}
```